# keyboard models vs layouts

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

My employer a small non-profit, is using an image of xubuntu created using clonezilla  to refurbish machines for our clients.  I would like to apply the 'right' keyboard model for whatever unit I happen to be working on.  Currently with the current version of xubuntu we are using (20.04) I have slim pickings. I note on the Ubuntu Mate Edition, there are many more newer models listed.  Perhaps my image is missing a package that would provide an updated model listing as well as keymaps.  What can I do to install/update the listing of keyboard models?

Regards,

T